# How to mock a module exporting a class with class variables using jest

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I have a module using `react-native-sound` in the following ways:

```
const Sound = require('react-native-sound');
...
const something = Sound.DOCUMENT;
const someOtherThing = new Sound();
```

How do I mock such a module?

Comment: For testing? Why are you mocking it?

Comment: Yes, I want to test a component which uses this module.

Comment: What is your testing framework? Jest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've mocked react-native-sound using a manual mock (in the __mocks__ folder) which looks like this:

```
const isFakeFilename = filename => /^blah.*/.test(filename);

const mockFunctions = {
  play: jest.fn(cb => {
    console.log('*** Playing sound! ***');
    cb && cb(isFakeFilename(this.filename) ? false : true);
  }),
  setCategory: jest.fn(),
  getDuration: jest.fn(() => 100),
  getNumberOfChannels: jest.fn(() => 8)
};

const Sound = function(filename, blah2, cb) {
  this.play = mockFunctions.play.bind(this);
  this.filename = filename;
  const savedFilename = filename;
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (isFakeFilename(savedFilename)) {
      cb && cb(new Error('File does not exist! (mocked condition)'));
    } else {
      cb && cb();
    }
  });
};

Sound.prototype.play = mockFunctions.play.bind(Sound.prototype);
Sound.prototype.getDuration = mockFunctions.getDuration;
Sound.prototype.getNumberOfChannels = mockFunctions.getNumberOfChannels;

Sound.setCategory = mockFunctions.setCategory;

export default Sound;
export { mockFunctions };
```

Note how methods on the Sound import are added directly (`Sound.setCategory`), and methods on instances of the class (`play`, `getDuration` etc.) are added using the prototype.

There's a little added complexity that you may not need using the `mockFunctions` export. I use that to check for calls to the mocked functions by importing it separately into the test file like

```
import { mockFunctions } from 'react-native-sound';
// ...
expect(mockFunctions.play).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: using the __mock__ folder it is impossible to have different mocked internals per test right?

Comment: You can change it on the fly using `mockImplementation` / `mockImplementationOnce`. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn. You'll need to import the mocked module into your test file to do this; see the example ('SomeClass') in the link.