# Unexpected Jest Errors when Mocking Uppy

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, uppy

I'm attempting to mock the `Uppy` class from the [uppy](https://github.com/transloadit/uppy) package in a Jest unit test following guidance from [this previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47606545/mock-a-dependencys-constructor-jest). My failing code is below:

```js
import Uppy from '@uppy/core';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    jest.mock('@uppy/core', () => {
      return {
        Uppy: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
          return {};
        }),
      };
    });
    
    new Uppy();
    expect(Uppy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

The test fails with the following error message:

```
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function Uppy]
```

It appears that the default export from `@uppy/core` is the `Uppy` class, so my expectation is that the provided code would mock the class' constructor, however this doesn't seem to be the case.

Package versions:

- Uppy: 2.1.2
- Jest: 27.4.7

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're using `jest.mock()` at the wrong time. In other words, I think it's *too late* to call `jest.mock()` inside a test case because the **package has already been imported** by that time.

I'm not sure what the canonical way of doing this is, but here is how React does it:

- it has a [separate file](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v18.0.0/scripts/jest/setupHostConfigs.js#L64) were `jest.mock()` is called
- that file's path from above is the value of Jest's [`globalSetup` option](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v18.0.0/scripts/jest/config.base.js#L4); as you can see, this option is the in the `config.base.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  globalSetup: require.resolve('./setupGlobal.js'),
}
```

- when the test script is run, it will [choose the config](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v18.0.0/scripts/jest/jest-cli.js#L255) based on the provided argument(s)
- an example of such config would be [this file](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v18.0.0/scripts/jest/config.source-www.js#L3) which, as you can see, extends `config.base`, which is where the `globalSetup` option has been set

```js
/* ... */
const baseConfig = require('./config.base');

module.exports = Object.assign({}, baseConfig, { /* ... */ });
/* ... */
```

So, I'd say that making use of that [`globalSetup` option](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globalsetup-string) should solve the problem.